# Unable to check whether a boolean is true?

Tags: boolean, lisp, common-lisp, equality

I am trying to check whether a boolean variable (`boolVariable`) is True (`T`) using the following code:

```
(defvar boolVariable T)

(if (= boolVariable T)
    (print 'TRUE)
)
```

However, I get the following error:

> - =: T is not a number

This seems strange, considering that I thought that you can check whether variables equal booleans in Lisp?

Comment: Note that the standard readtable upcases all symbols, so your `boolVariable` is actually `BOOLVARIABLE`.  In Lisp the convention is to use kebab-case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Common Lisp's [=](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eq_sle.htm#EQ) compares only numbers and neither `t` nor `boolVariable` is number.

There are some other equality predicates like [eq](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw71/CLHS/Body/f_eq.htm#eq), [eql](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw71/CLHS/Body/f_eql.htm), [equal](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw71/CLHS/Body/f_equal.htm#equal) or [equalp](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw71/CLHS/Body/f_equalp.htm#equalp), but in this case, you can just use value of `bool-variable` (renamed in kebab-case):

```
(defvar bool-variable t)
(if bool-variable (print 'TRUE))
```

[`If`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_if.htm) with only `then-form` can be also replaced with [`when`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_when_.htm):

```
(defvar bool-variable t)
(when bool-variable (print 'TRUE))
```